# Broken relative Url in jQuery getJSON Ajax Method

Tags: url, jquery, getjson

The Url for my development environment is:

```
http://localhost/mysite/blah...
```

I am using jQuery & getJSON to perform some ajax actions on my site, which work fine all the time I specify the url as:

```
/mysite/controller/action
```

..but this is not ideal as I don't want to hardcode my development url into my seperate jQuery include files.

When the site goes live, it'll be fine to have controller/action or /controller/action as the url as that will resolve ok, but for the development site, it's no go.

I've tried:

```
controller/action
```

..but this returns a 404, which suprised me as I thought the lack of / at the front of the url would prevent from looking at the website root.

There must be a neat solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this by inserting a global constant in my HTML header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var BASE_URL = '/mysite/';
</script>
```

That would be inserted from your server so it can be dynamically changed.
Later in your script, you'll be able to make AJAX requests with (jQuery style here):

```
$.ajax( BASE_URL + '/controller/action', ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in

```
/mysite/controller/action
```

then the correct relative path to

```
/mysite/some_other_controller/some_other_action
```

is

```
../../some_other_controller/some_other/action
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not always going to be called from the same path, and so whilst the ../../ will work in some areas - it will fail in others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the current path of the .js script and use it for calculate your relative path.

```
var url;
$("script").each(function () {
       if ($(this).attr("src").indexOf("[YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.JS]") > 0) {
                url = $(this).attr("src");
                url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
                return false;
       }
});
var final_url = url + "/your_target_script.js"
```

Replace YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME with the unique name of your script.